# How to set a static ip for a Ubuntu server in VMWare

Tags: networking, server, vmware

I am trying to play with some DNS in VM's in VMWare running on my mac.

When I set up a NAT network adaptor in a 10.1.100.0/24 network. I can ping the internet and my home network (With DHCP set). But if I set the server to a static ip say 10.1.100.10 by editing the /etc/network/interfaces file. It will take the new address on reboot but now I cant ping the internet.

If I run netstat -nr I can see that the 0.0.0.0 dest is set to a gateway of 10.1.100.2 when set on DHCP.

I have set the gateway to the same address but I still cant get out of the network to the internet.

How do I need to set up the networking to be able to have IPs set static and still be able connect to the internet as well.

Comment: What does "ping the internet" mean here? What are the actual contents of /etc/network/interfaces? Don't forget that DHCP usually provides more than just a host IP (in particular - one or more nameservers)

Comment: I cant ping 8.8.8.8 as well.